# how migration jetspeed-1.5.jar to jetspeed-2.x for java eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, migration, jetspeed2

i'm a beginner programmer and i want update jetspeed-1.5 library to jetspeed-2.x .

I have already consulted http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/j1-migration.html but i haven't an idea how to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/j1-migration.html) provides the guidelines for migration because there are currently no migration tools. The programming API is completely changed. There are also new concepts introduced by the portlet standard. Your best bet would be follow the [guidelines](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/j1-migration.html) to migrate application from Jetspeed 1.x to Jetspeed 2.

As recommended in the guideline, the best place to get started is to create your own custom portal. This process is defined online at Apache. The Jetspeed [Tutorial](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/tutorial/index.html) will take you through the initial steps of setting up your own (custom) Jetspeed portal, including setting up XML seed data, PSML, custom decorations and portlet applications.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You can give me the apache link that creates a custom portal

Comment: The Jetspeed Tutorial - http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/tutorial/index.html will take you through the initial steps of setting up your own (custom) Jetspeed portal.